# Why is my function representation not reverse-copying data?

Tags: c, io, fwrite

I have this function representation of `fwrite` that write bytes backwards. However.. it doesn't really copy them backwards which appears to be really strange.

```
size_t fwrite_backward ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream )
{
    int i, chr;

    for(i = count * size; i != 0; i--)
    {
        if( fputc(*(unsigned char*)ptr + (count * size) - i, stream) != EOF )
        chr++;
    }
    return chr;
}
```

It is supposed to behave exactly like `fwrite` with two differences:

- It copies data backwards
- It doesn't set `ferror`

What i might be doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: Try stepping through your code, either in your head or with a debugger.  What is the value of `i` in the first iteration of the loop?  What is the index of the first byte written in the first iteration?

Comment: You don't initialize `chr` (presumably it should be set to zero).  However, that's not the main problem.

Comment: Oh The loop is actually reversal.. And yes.. i forgot to initialize `chr` thank you..

Comment: Yes, you have two methods of reversing the order of the data in use at once, which means that the one counteracts the other.

Comment: You also pass a pointer to `fputc` where you should pass a value.

Comment: I changed the loop direction. Whats next? "The index of the first byte writtein in the first iteration"? I'm pretty sure `ptr` has the offset of the first byte of the instance.

Comment: And you should probably break out of the loop when `fputc` encounters an error. And for compatiblity with `fwrite`, on which your function is modelled, you should return the number of items written, `chr / size`, rather than the number of bytes.

Comment: @MOehm I will fix this. I misswrote the asterisk.

Comment: @Corelation: Switching on warnings would have told you about the wrong parameter type. Might want to make that a habit.

Comment: @MOehm There wasn't any warning. And i actually wrote it correct THERE. However.. this fix R Sahu provided seems to cause the same result.

Comment: What dou you mean, you wrote it correct there? That you didn't post the original code? With regard to warnings: A failing of many C compilers is that you have to switch them on explicitly, e.g. with ´-Wall` for gcc. There should have been a warning either about a missing prototype or about an argument type mismatch. I got one, anyway.

Comment: @MOehm Yes I didn't post the original code. I didn't copy/paste it too. And I wrote it here. Why is it still not working and copying them noturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation below seems to work. It also corrects some minor design flaws of your version:

- Your code writes out all *bytes* backwards, but you should write all *items* backwards with the bytes in the items themselves in the original order. (After all, what's the distinction between `size` and `count` for?) The code below works with items of any size.
- Yor code returns the number of bytes written. But `fwrite` returns the number of items written.
- The loop ends early on unsuccessful writes.

So:

```
size_t fwrite_rev(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *stream)
{
    const unsigned char *p = ptr;
    size_t written = 0;

    while (count--) {
        if (fwrite(p + size * count, size, 1, stream) < 1) break;
        written++;
    }

    return written;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The indexing used to get the byte for `fputc` is wrong. Also, you are dereferencing the pointer incorrectly.

The expression `*(unsigned char*)ptr + (count * size) - i` is equivalent to:

```
 char c = *(unsigned char*)ptr, (c + count*size - i)
```

which is definitely not what you are looking for.

Instead of

```
    if( fputc(*(unsigned char*)ptr + (count * size) - i, stream) != EOF )
```

it should be

```
    if( fputc(*((unsigned char*)ptr + i - 1), stream) != EOF )
```

or

```
    if( fputc(((unsigned char*)ptr)[i - 1], stream) != EOF )
```

Comment: It should be `((unsigned char *)ptr)[i - 1]`, because `fputc` requires a value, not a pointer.

Comment: The result is still in the correct order and not reversed.

Comment: No idea, C89, `char arr[3] = { '3', '2', '1' };` to reverse and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Corelation: You either need `for (int i = 0; i < count * size; i++) fputc(((unsigned char *)ptr)[count * size - i - 1], stream);` or `for (int i = count * size; i > 0; i--) fputc(((unsigned char *)ptr)[i], stream);` but you should not simultaneously count down and operate from the end of the string as you are doing (attempting to do) at the moment.  I'd also set up the pointer once, outside the loop, and similarly with the loop limits expressions, so the the body of the loop is simpler to understand.  Those casts make it unreadable.